# Place rectangles randomly but not within x radius in the center

Tags: javascript, math, raphael

How can I place rectangles with variable width and height, randomly in a stage but away from a circle in the center which has radius of x

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

check my code so far

http://jsfiddle.net/chchrist/cAShH/1/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've entered a minimized version of my code

Comment: if the cirle is in the middle of the 400x400 (center in 200x200), you could calculate position to check if it's 50px away from that point in any given direction.

Comment: So simplified 150 is ok but 151 is not ok and 250 is ok but 249 is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a coordinate system centered at 0,0 and after you have generated valid coordinates map them onto your square/rectangle.

Here's a simple example:

```
function getValidCoordinates() {
    var x, y, isValid = false;

    while (!isValid) {
        x = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        y = Math.random() * 400 - 200;

        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)) > 50)
            isValid = true;
        //else alert('too close ' + x + ',' + y);
    }

    return {x: x + 200, y: y + 200};
}

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    var co = getValidCoordinates();
    alert('x=' + co.x + ', y=' + co.y);
}
```

Comment: You use Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance? Will there be a problem I apply those x,y to boxes with width:100 and height:20?

Comment: This just generates points that are outside of the central circle.  It becomes more complex when you have boxes of a rectangular nature which need to "entirely reside outside the circle" (is that right?)  If they were circles you could just add the radius of the circle to the 50px radius of the central circle (ie, exclusion radius is 50 + r).  How precise do you need this?

Comment: I need to fill a stage with n boxes with no overlap and keep them away from the center of the stage in x radius. Dimensions of the stage, boxes and radius may change...

Answer (score 2):

The three potential options I would follow are:

- Generate random coordinates in [400,400] and then check that the distance from [200,200] is less than 50. If it is, fine; if not, start again.
- Generate random polar coordinates (i.e., angle and distance), where the distance is greater than 50. Then convert these to Cartesian, centred around [200,200] and bounded to your area... The problem with this approach is that it would introduce bias at the extremities of your rectangular area.
- Ignore the circle and bound it by a square, then use the first approach but with simplified logic.

Comment: To add to my second point, you may be able to map the circular annulus generated by the simplistic polar coordinates, that I suggested, arbitrarily close to a "rectangular annulus": your square with a hole in the middle... Perhaps a tad over-engineered, though!!

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to think about how to map uniform random numbers into legal positions.

For example (simplifying slightly), if you had a 200 x 200 square, and you wanted to avoid any points in a 100x100 square in the middle, you could do the following for each coordinate.  Generate a random number between 0 and 100.  If it's less than 50, use it directly; otherwise add 100 to it (to put it in the 150-200 range)

Conceptually this stretches the range around the "hole" in the middle, while still leaving the resulting points uniformly distributed.

It'll be trickier with your circle, as the axes are not independent, but a variation on this method could be worth considering.  (Especially if you only have "soft" requirements for randomness and so can relax the constraints on the distribution somewhat).

Comment: I can't understand the add 150 to part of your answer

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer.  The square is 200 x 200, but there's a 100 x 100 section in the middle that we want to avoid.  So the valid ranges for a coordinate are 0-50 (before the square) and then 150-200 (after the square).  So you want to map a number from 0 to 100 into the union of these ranges; the first half of the random range maps into the "before" section, and the latter half of the random range maps into the "after" section.  Except given these constraints, it's really **100** that should be added - answer edited.